# Category List item in Sharepoint 2010 Blog Template

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to rename the Category List in Sharepoint 2010 Blog Template.

Answer (score 4):

The Category List can be renamed as any other list in the List Settings.
The header in the blog navigation on the home page of a blog template will not be updated by this. The header 'Categories' is defined in wss.resx(or a locale) and referenced in blog.xsl.